# Serilog HTTP Sink custom formatting for Logstash

Tags: json, asp.net-core, format, logstash, serilog

I am using [Serilog HTTP sink](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http) for logging to Logstash in my .Net Core Project. In startup.cs I have following code to enable serilog.

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Http("http://mylogstashhost.com:5000").Enrich.WithProperty("user", "xxx").Enrich.WithProperty("serviceName", "yyy")
        .MinimumLevel.Warning()
        .CreateLogger();
```

And this code sends logs to the given http address. I can see on fiddler that following json is being posted to the logstash and logstash returns "ok" message.

```
{"events":[{"Timestamp":"2018-10-19T18:16:27.6561159+01:00","Level":"Warning","MessageTemplate":"abc","RenderedMessage":"abc","user":"xxx","serviceName":"yyy","Properties":{"ActionId":"b313b8ed-0baf-4d75-a6e2-f0dbcb941f67","ActionName":"MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.Index","RequestId":"0HLHLQMV1EBCJ:00000003","RequestPath":"/"}}]}
```

But when I checked on Kibana, I can not see this log. I tried to figure out what causes it and i realized that if I send the json as following format I can see the Log.

```
{"Timestamp":"2018-10-19T18:16:27.6561159+01:00","Level":"Warning","MessageTemplate":"abc","RenderedMessage":"abc","user":"xxx","serviceName":"yyy","Properties":{"ActionId":"b313b8ed-0baf-4d75-a6e2-f0dbcb941f67","ActionName":"MyProject.Controllers.HomeController.Index" ,"RequestId":"0HLHLQMV1EBCJ:00000003","RequestPath":"/"}}
```

So Logstash doesnt like the event to be in Events{} and also it wants "user" and "ServiceName" tags out of "Properties". Is there a way to format my Json like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after some research and help, basically to achieve custom formats, one should implement interfaces like ITextFormatter, BatchFormatter etc.

I could achieve the format i need, by modifying ArrayBatchFormatter a little:

```
public class MyFormat : BatchFormatter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ArrayBatchFormatter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventBodyLimitBytes">
    /// The maximum size, in bytes, that the JSON representation of an event may take before it
    /// is dropped rather than being sent to the server. Specify null for no limit. Default
    /// value is 256 KB.
    /// </param>
    public MyFormat(long? eventBodyLimitBytes = 256 * 1024): base(eventBodyLimitBytes)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Format the log events into a payload.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logEvents">
    /// The events to format.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="output">
    /// The payload to send over the network.
    /// </param>
    public override void Format(IEnumerable<string> logEvents, TextWriter output)
    {
        if (logEvents == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logEvents));
        if (output == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

        // Abort if sequence of log events is empty
        if (!logEvents.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        output.Write("[");

        var delimStart = string.Empty;

        foreach (var logEvent in logEvents)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(logEvent))
            {
                continue;
            }
            int index = logEvent.IndexOf("{");

            string adjustedString = "{\"user\":\"xxx\",\"serviceName\" : \"yyy\"," + logEvent.Substring(1);
            if (CheckEventBodySize(adjustedString))
            {
                output.Write(delimStart);
                output.Write(adjustedString);
                delimStart = ",";
            }
        }

        output.Write("]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend @nooaa answer with this variation. Instead of manipulating the string to add new objects, I would suggest using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`. This way you can append, add or remove existing properties of the object itself.

Also, instead of doing `output.write` after each event, you can combine all the output from the events and do `output.write` once at the end (a bit of performance)

```
public override void Format(IEnumerable<string> logEvents, TextWriter output)
{
    if (logEvents == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logEvents));
    if (output == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));

    // Abort if sequence of log events is empty
    if (!logEvents.Any())
    {
        return;
    }
    
    List<object> updatedEvents = new List<object>();
    foreach (string logEvent in logEvents)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(logEvent))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Parse the log event
        var obj = JObject.Parse(logEvent);

        // Add New entries 
        obj["@source_host"] = obj["fields"]["MachineName"].Value<string>().ToLower();

        // Remove any entries you are not interested in
        ((JObject)obj["fields"]).Remove("MachineName");
                
        // Default tags for any log that goes out of your app.
        obj["@tags"] = new JArray() { "appName", "api" };

        // Additional tags from end points (custom based on routes)
        if (obj["fields"]["tags"] != null) 
        {
            ((JArray)obj["@tags"]).Merge((JArray)obj["fields"]["tags"]);
            ((JObject)obj["fields"]).Remove("tags");
        }
       
        updatedEvents.Add(obj);
    }

    output.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatedEvents));
}
```

**Update**
[Release Notes v8.0.0](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http/releases)

1. With latest release, you dont override the method anymore.

```
namespace Serilog.Sinks.Http.BatchFormatters {
  public class MyCustomFormatter: IBatchFormatter {
    public void Format(IEnumerable<string> logEvents, TextWriter output) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

2. you don't provide any Contructors for it either.
3. Add queueLimitBytes along with `batchFormatter` and `textFormatter`

```
WriteTo.Http(new Uri(), 
  batchFormatter: new MyCustomFormatter(),
  queueLimitBytes: 50 * ByteSize.MB,
  textFormatter: new ElasticsearchJsonFormatter());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply process the batch file in logstash changing the pipeline as recommended by https://blog.romanpavlov.me/logging-serilog-elk/

```
# Http input listening port 8080
input {
    http {  
        #default host 0.0.0.0:8080
        codec => json
    }
}

# Separate the logs
filter {
    split {
        field => "events"
        target => "e"
        remove_field => "events"
    }
}

# Send the logs to Elasticsearch
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        index=>"customer-%{+xxxx.ww}"
    }
}
```